# Kafka Streams cannot consume and process message from input topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I write a sample(word count) kafka stream program, I find it cannot consume and process any message from the input topic when it running, but my consume program can get all message from the input topic, I don't know what's wrong with my code.

my kafka is running with docker

```
docker run -d\
    -p 19092:9092 \
    --name kafka1 \
    -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0 \
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=192.168.31.231:12181 \
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://192.168.31.231:19092 \
    -e KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 \
    wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.4.0
```

my stream code

```
public class WordCountLambdaExample {

    static final String inputTopic = "streams-plaintext-input";
    static final String outputTopic = "streams-plaintext-output";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String bootstrapServers = "localhost:19092";

        final Properties streamsConfiguration = getStreamsConfiguration(bootstrapServers);

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        createWordCountStream(builder);
        System.out.println(builder.build().describe());
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
        streams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }

    static Properties getStreamsConfiguration(final String bootstrapServers) {
        final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example-client");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1 * 1000);
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
        streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        return streamsConfiguration;
    }

    static void createWordCountStream(final StreamsBuilder builder) {
        final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream(inputTopic);
        textLines.print(Printed.<String, String>toSysOut().withLabel("My Stream App"));
        KTable<String, Long> wordcounts =
                textLines.mapValues(value -> value.toLowerCase())
                        .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(" ")))
                        .selectKey((k, v) -> v)
                        .groupByKey()
                        .count();
        wordcounts.toStream().to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
    }

}
```

my gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'online.mychat'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.9

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-streams', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest` instead `latest`. Apart of that insure that your application's group (`StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG`) doesn't commit any offset earlier.

According to documentation [Consumer configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs):

> **auto.offset.reset:** What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server
>   (e.g. because that data has been deleted):
>
> - earliest: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
> - latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset
> - none: throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group
> - anything else: throw exception to the consumer.
>
> Type: stringDefault: latestValid Values: [latest, earliest,
>   none]Importance: medium